# Envelope made by normals

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A curve passes through $(0,1)$ at a maximum point where the  tangent is parallel to x-axis. Slope of tangent to the curve at any point $ ( x, y)  $  is given by ode:

$$ \cos \phi =y^2 $$

How can one find the envelope made by its normals?

Thought the calculation is similar to finding a caustic... but there is only a single equation here.

EDIT1:

Is it possible to find $x,y$ in terms of parameter $\phi?$